# How to add properties to topojson file?

Tags: json, topojson

**Given a data.tsv file such :**

```
id  code    name
1   AL  Alabama
2   AK  Alaska
4   AZ  Arizona
5   AR  Arkansas
6   CA  California
... ... ...
```

**Given a topojson.json file such :** (the structure is correct, the numeral values are random)

```
{ 
"type":"Topology",
"transform": 
    {
    "scale": [0.0015484881821515486,0.0010301030103010299],
    "translate":[-5.491666666666662,41.008333333333354]
    },
"objects": 
    {
    "states":
        {
        "type":"GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": 
            [
            {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"code_2":"AL"}},
            {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"code_2":"AK"}}
            ]
        }
    },
"arcs":
    [
        [[2466,9916],[-25,-5],[3,-13]],
        [[2357,9852],[1,-2],[1,-2]]
    ]
}
```

**How to use the common fields(1) to inject the values of an other field(2) into the json file ?**

1]: `data.txt#code` and `topojson.txt.objects.states.geometries.properties.code_2`

2]: `data.txt#name`

The end result should contains :

```
            {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"code_2":"AL", "name":"Alabama" }},
            {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"code_2":"AK", "name":"Alaska" }},
```

---

**EDIT: Accepted answer:**

```
topojson -o final.json -e data.tsv --id-property=code_2,code -p code_2,state=name -- topojson.json
```

Comment: I lightly edited the topojson so the both shape are conserved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using this:

```
    topojson -o final.json -e data.tsv \
        --id-property=code_2,code -p code_2,state=name \
        -- topojson.json
```

Which should output:

```js
    {
        "type": "Topology",
        "transform": {
            "scale": [
                0.000016880209206372492,
                0.000007005401010148724
            ],
            "translate": [ -1.8418800213354616, 51.15278777877789 ]
        },
        "objects": {
            "states": {
                "type": "GeometryCollection",
                "geometries": [
                    {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "arcs": [
                            [ 0 ]
                        ],
                        "id": "AK",
                        "properties": {
                            "code_2": "AK",
                            "state": "Alaska"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "arcs": [
            [[2466,9916],[-25,-5],[3,-13]],
            [[2357,9852],[1,-2],[1,-2]]
        ]
    }
```

From the [Command Line Reference wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference):

> **--id-property** name of feature property to promote to geometry id

By using the `code_2` property with this option, you promote it as the feature ID.

> Prepend a **+** in front of the input property name to coerce its value to a number.

Plus:

> If the properties referenced by **--id-property** are null or undefined,
> they are **omitted** from the output geometry object. Thus, the generated
> objects may not have a defined ID if the input features did not have a
> property with the specified name.

So, when you are using `+code` and `+code_2`, they are probably `undefined`, as you can't convert the `AK` string value to a number.

> Here, the input property "FIPS" is coerced to a number and used as the
> feature identifier; likewise, the column named "FIPS" is used as the
> identifier in the CSV file. (If your CSV file uses a different column
> name for the feature identifier, you can specify multiple id
> properties, such as `--id-property=+FIPS,+id`.)

That's why you have to add the `code` to the `--id-property=code_2,code` option. This is how the mapping is made (the `code_2` from *topojson.json* and the `code` column from *data.tsv*).

> Then, the output property "unemployment" is generated from the
> external data file, unemployment.tsv, which defines the input property
> "rate"

In our case, `-p code_2,state=name` specifies that we will preserve the `code_2` property and we will rename the `name` property to `state`. The **Properties** and **External Properties** sections in the aforementioned documentation wiki are pretty informative on the matter.

Comment: If I could, I would +1 several times.

Comment: This no longer works. I have a topojson.json file and -p doesn't add new attributes. It only preserves what's already in the geojson. Maybe my file is unique. Would love to find a solution.

Comment: Hi , I went through the answer and formed thebelow command but now  topojson is renamed to geo2topo command.  geo2topo   -o output.json  -e data1.csv   --id-property=adm1_code,code  -p adm1_code,statename=state  -- states_topo.json.    This command is not working.  In order to add extra property is there different command name  other than geo2topo ?

Comment: How can we use this command line solution if we don't have Node? I'm simply am using `<src=` tags to use topojsonv1.js Is there something we can do within a text editor/ within the html? (aside from parsing the external properties one at a time)

Comment: @AnandSonake I have just posted an answer based on current command-line interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The [topojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson) package has been deprecated. The following steps are based on the [command-line cartography](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-2-c3a82c5c0f3) workflow. These interfaces are more flexible, but a little bit more complicated to use.

Install dependencies:

`npm install d3-dsv ndjson-cli`

Add the node_modules/.bin directory to the path so that you can easily run the commands:

`PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH`

Convert the tsv file into a newline-delimited json file:

`tsv2json data.tsv -n > data.ndjson`

```
{"id":"1","code":"AL","name":"Alabama"}
{"id":"2","code":"AK","name":"Alaska"}
```

Parse the id column as a number:

`ndjson-map '{id: +d.id, code: d.code, name: d.name}' < data.ndjson > data_parsed.ndjson`

```
{"id":1,"code":"AL","name":"Alabama"}
{"id":2,"code":"AK","name":"Alaska"}
```

Extract the geometries of the topojson file:

`ndjson-cat topojson.json | ndjson-split 'd.objects.states.geometries' > topojson_geometries.ndjson`

```
{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"code_2":"AK"}}
{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"code_2":"AL"}}
```

Join both newline-delimited json files:

`ndjson-join 'd.properties.code_2' 'd.code' topojson_geometries.ndjson data_parsed.ndjson > geometries_data_join.ndjson`

```
[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"code_2":"AK"}},{"id":2,"code":"AK","name":"Alaska"}]
[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"code_2":"AL"}},{"id":1,"code":"AL","name":"Alabama"}]
```

Add the name column to the topojson properties and only keep the topojson geometries:

`ndjson-map 'd[0].properties.name = d[1].name, d[0]' < geometries_data_join.ndjson > geometries_data_merge.ndjson`

```
{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"code_2":"AK","name":"Alaska"}}
{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"code_2":"AL","name":"Alabama"}}
```

Convert the previous result into an array and concat it with the original topojson file:

`ndjson-join <(ndjson-cat topojson.json) <(ndjson-reduce < geometries_data_merge.ndjson) > topojson_concat.ndjson`

```
[{
    "type": "Topology",
    "transform": {
        "scale": [0.0015484881821515486, 0.0010301030103010299],
        "translate": [-5.491666666666662, 41.008333333333354]
    },
    "objects": {
        "states": {
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "geometries": [{
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "arcs": [[0]],
                    "properties": {
                        "code_2": "AK"
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "arcs": [[1]],
                    "properties": {
                        "code_2": "AL"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "arcs": [[[2466, 9916], [-25, -5], [3, -13]], [[2357, 9852], [1, -2], [1, -2]]]
    }, [{
            "type": "Polygon",
            "arcs": [[0]],
            "properties": {
                "code_2": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "arcs": [[1]],
            "properties": {
                "code_2": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

Overwrite the geometries of original topojson file and save it as a normal json file:

`ndjson-map 'd[0].objects.states.geometries = d[1], d[0]' < topojson_concat.ndjson > topojson_data.json`

```
{
    "type": "Topology",
    "transform": {
        "scale": [0.0015484881821515486, 0.0010301030103010299],
        "translate": [-5.491666666666662, 41.008333333333354]
    },
    "objects": {
        "states": {
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "geometries": [{
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "arcs": [[0]],
                    "properties": {
                        "code_2": "AK",
                        "name": "Alaska"
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "arcs": [[1]],
                    "properties": {
                        "code_2": "AL",
                        "name": "Alabama"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "arcs": [[[2466, 9916], [-25, -5], [3, -13]], [[2357, 9852], [1, -2], [1, -2]]]
}
```

All commands in one line:

```
ndjson-join <(ndjson-cat topojson.json) <(ndjson-join 'd.properties.code_2' 'd.code' <(ndjson-cat topojson.json | ndjson-split 'd.objects.states.geometries') <(tsv2json data.tsv -n | ndjson-map '{id: +d.id, code: d.code, name: d.name}') | ndjson-map 'd[0].properties.name = d[1].name, d[0]' | ndjson-reduce) | ndjson-map 'd[0].objects.states.geometries = d[1], d[0]' > topojson_data.json
```

Notes:

- I swapped "AK" and "AL" in the topojson file to check if the join really works.
- The last command (before the one-liner) only works on the original output and not on the given pretty-printed version, which has newlines in it.
- I tested the workflow on the subsystem for Linux since ndjson-map does not seem to work properly on Windows currently.

Comment: This is surprizingly complex indeed.