# Combining additional data with Shapefile using GeoJSON and Gdal

Tags: csv, maps, gdal, geojson, topojson

I used Mike Bostock's great tutorial to make a simple map using downloaded shapefiles and processing them with GDAL into GeoJSON files.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

I'm trying to build on this learning by taking a county-level shapefile map and marrying it with additional demographic data (CSV) so that I can load a single GeoJSON file and not have to use Javascript to merge the data at runtime. The goal is to have a county-level heatmap.

The CSV file has an ID column that looks like this: `01348`. While the Shapefile has two ID columns that are `01` and `348`.

Is it possible to use GeoJSON to store this kind of data? If so, what kind of terminal commands must I use to combine the two?

Comment: Issue opened there: http://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little trick:

1. When converting from Shape file to GeoJSON, keep `"id-a":"01";"id-b":"348"` as neighbors in this order.
2. use a simple regex to delete all `";"id-b":"` and thus obtain `"id-a":"01348"`.
3. go ahead to inject your CSV property given the common ID, see: [How to add properties to topojson file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/)

That's should work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and pointing me in the right direction. I'll check this out and see how it goes.