# Can topoJSON create composite properties?

Tags: gis, topojson

Using [topoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) is it possible to take two properties from an input shapefile and combine them into a single property on the output topoJSON file?

For example if the feature on the original shapefile has the properties 'constituency':'34' and 'ward':'90' is it possible to concatenate these into a single id property in the output JSON file 'id':'3490'?

If not, can anyone suggest an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560541/ , a smooth process would be interesting to get.

Comment: Yes, at the moment I'm doing it using a CSV to look up the concatenated values. It works fine though the extra step is a bit messy. I thought it might be nice to have something like ' -p id=constituency&ward ' seems like this would be a fairly common task (i've encountered the problem a couple of times now) but maybe not.

Comment: I would love it too....... I guess the best would be [to fill a feature request](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues) on Github. Bostock should be happy to implement it (if not already secretly there)

Comment: Issue opened there: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/107

Comment: Github issue is showing some activity, seems Mike & al. may output some sweet solutions within days/weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This is now possible.
As of [this commit](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/commit/c755c48fc52d359852d56c24f6dafa841698830b) `-p id=constituency+""+ward` will concatenate *constituency* and *ward* properties on the input file into an *id* property on the output file. The **""** between *constituency* and *ward* coerces to strings ensuring javascript doesn't simply add two integers i.e. `30+24` gives 54  `30+""+24` gives 3024.