# topojson keep and remove properties

Tags: topojson

How to run the below command to remove properties? When I install topojson the executable I get is geo2topo. The command topojson is unrecognised. So, how to run the below command with geo2topo.

```
topojson --id-property adm1_cod_1 -p name -o states_jpn.topo.json states_jpn.json
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TopoJSON Properties Preservation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095316/topojson-properties-preservation)

Comment: `topojson` executable has been removed and replaced with `geo2json` See this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095316/topojson-properties-preservation) for an anwser.